# More upvotes per day for moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators, voting

I have noticed that the moderators in Ask Ubuntu Genral Room seem to say that they run out of votes for the day each day. And I know from experience that there are more then 40 great posts each day on Ask Ubuntu. So, should the moderators be allowed more votes? Or, should more votes be added as a privilege for high-ranking users? If so, how many additional votes should be allowed? Please leave feedback.

Answer (score 11):

I'm against this for the reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109018/152101) by Robert Cartaino (An SE employee) when this came up a while ago on Meta Stack Overflow.

> The daily vote limit used to be 30 votes per day; we’ve increased that
>   to a maximum of 40 votes per day (provided some of those votes go to
>   questions).
>
> Already, it is so exceedingly rare for users to even hit the 30 vote
>   daily cap, most users are not even aware that there is a limit. Still,
>   there needs to be a limit.
>
> Reputation is awarded by the community to the users for good content.
>   There is an "economy" to the site with reputation as its currency, and
>   voting drives that economy. But for that currency to have value, it
>   has to be a limited resource. Users have to apportion their votes to
>   their favorite content. That's what gives the award value.
>
> [Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits)
>
> If you are routinely using your daily allotment, that puts you well up
>   into the +99 percentile of users. That's fantastic; I'm glad you are a
>   conscientious voter. But if the limit was 50, somebody would want 60.
>   If not 60, then 70. You see where I am going with this. There needs to
>   be a limit, and 40 seems just about right, or the apportionment of
>   voting would become increasingly skewed from a small minority of
>   users.

Comment: OK, good points. I'd like to hear what a moderator has to say on this issue too.

Comment: What John said.

Comment: +1 to john "dogs always want more"